# javascript: Form is not getting submiited only IE, but, it works all other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

On this code, this is working perfectly, it checks all the `if` condition and its okay in all the browsers except IE8 and IE. when all the login values are entered correctly, then, while submiting the form, it working all browsers except IE, IE8, why it is not working in IE8? Any clue?

This below will be displayed when all the inputs are okay. This is not working in IE8. Any help?

```
<div id="FormSubmit" class="FormSubmit">
        <p>Form submitted successfully</p>
</div>
```

I don't know where the exact problem. It works in rest of the browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IEStyles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <![endif]-->
      </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

    <div id="FormSubmit" class="FormSubmit">
    <p>Form submitted successfully</p>
    </div>
    <div class="LogIn">
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm(this);"> 
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Firstname Lastname"/>
    <span class="user-name">Name should not be empty</span>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Confirm password"/>
    <span class="password">Password does not be match</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <span class="email">Email is not valid</span>
    <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="Website"/>
    <span class="urlcontent">Invalid Website URL</span>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form></div> </div>    

<script type="text/javascript">    
var browserName;
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("password1")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("url")[0].value="";
document.getElementById("FormSubmit").style.display="none";
document.querySelector('span[class="user-name"]').style.display="none";
document.querySelector('span[class="password"]').style.display="none";
document.querySelector('span[class="urlcontent"]').style.display="none";
document.querySelector('span[class="email"]').style.display="none";
document.getElementsByName("username")[0].focus();
browserName = navigator.appName;
//alert(browserName);
} 

function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 

function validateURL(curUrl){
alert("Hey, ULLLL"); 
  var re = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/;
    return re.test(curUrl);
}

 function validateForm(form) {
  var returnValue=true;
  if(loginForm.username.value.length < 6){
  returnValue = false;
  document.querySelector('span[class="user-name"]').style.display="";
  loginForm.username.value = "";
  loginForm.username.focus();
  return returnValue;

}
 if (loginForm.password.value.length < 6){
  returnValue = false;
 alert("Your password must be at least\n6 characters long.\n Please try again.");
 loginForm.password.value = "";
 loginForm.password1.value = "";
 loginForm.password.focus();
 return returnValue;
}                  
if (loginForm.password.value != loginForm.password1.value){
returnValue = false;
document.querySelector('span[class="password"]').style.display="";
loginForm.password.value = "";
loginForm.password1.value = "";
loginForm.password1.focus();
return returnValue;
} 
if (loginForm.url.value.length == 0){
  returnValue = false;
 document.querySelector('span[class="urlcontent"]').style.display="";
 loginForm.url.focus();
 return returnValue;
}   

if ((loginForm.email.value.length != 0) && (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")){
  returnValue = false;
 var imEmail = validateEmail(loginForm.email.value);
 returnValue = imEmail;
 if (returnValue == false) document.querySelector('span[class="email"]').style.display="";

 loginForm.email.focus();
 return returnValue;

} 

if ((loginForm.url.value.length != 0) && (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")){
  //alert("Yessssssss!");
  returnValue = false;
 var imURL = validateURL(loginForm.url.value);
 returnValue = imURL;
 if (returnValue == false) document.querySelector('span[class="urlcontent"]').style.display="";
 loginForm.url.focus();//alert(returnValue);
 return returnValue;
}

if(returnValue!=false) {

document.getElementById("FormSubmit").style.display="";

return false;
   }
} 

</script>



  </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get in IE?

Comment: Errors? Please check the console and see if you have any errors. You need to show that you have made efforts to try and track down the error for yourself, rather than just saying - "This doesn't work".

Comment: @putvande, i did not get any error. I dont have any on what is the issue.

Comment: It might be the `document.querySelector`?

Comment: Check your `querySelector` results. Acording to http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector some selectors may not be supported

Comment: Note that having a form control with a name of "submit" masks the form's submit method so you can't call it. There is no need for the submit button to have a name, so just remove it. Oh, and get rid of `javascript:` in the form's *onsubmit* attribute, it is seen as a useless label.

Comment: @RobG, I am not getting your point, pls explain bit further

Comment: Reduce your code to the minimum that displays the issue (get rid of the entire head, the menus, etc. and as many validation functions as you can), then maybe there's a chance someone can find your (unexplained) error. I can't see how `if ((loginForm.email.value.length != 0) && (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")){
  returnValue = false;` makes any sense.

Comment: Your form doesn't have an `action` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE it is return at here:

```
if ((loginForm.email.value.length != 0) && (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")){
    returnValue = false;
    var imEmail = validateEmail(loginForm.email.value);
    returnValue = imEmail;
    if (returnValue == false) document.querySelector('span[class="email"]').style.display="";

    loginForm.email.focus();
    return returnValue;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

In which the `if` statement is actually like this:

```
if (returnValue == false) {document.querySelector('span[class="email"]').style.display="";}
                          ^                                                               ^
loginForm.email.focus();
return returnValue;
```

I guess what you want is return when it is false. You really should wrap `if` statement with braces, otherwise only the first statement is under the check

```
if (returnValue == false) {
    document.querySelector('span[class="email"]').style.display="";
    loginForm.email.focus();
    return returnValue;
}
```

Same for "loginForm.url"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following javascript:

```
(function () {
var
style = document.createStyleSheet(),
select = function (selector, maxCount) {
var
all = document.all,
l = all.length,
i,
resultSet = [];

style.addRule(selector, "foo:bar");
for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
if (all[i].currentStyle.foo === "bar") {
resultSet.push(all[i]);
if (resultSet.length > maxCount) {
break;
}
}
}
style.removeRule(0);
return resultSet;

};

// be rly sure not to destroy a thing!
if (document.querySelectorAll || document.querySelector) {
return;
}

document.querySelectorAll = function (selector) {
return select(selector, Infinity);
};
document.querySelector = function (selector) {
return select(selector, 1)[0] || null;
};
}());
```

I tried it and it works. Found the link at: 
https://gist.github.com/Fusselwurm/4673695